# RegDeleteKey and RegDeleteKeyEx

Tags: windows, winapi, registry

I am writing an app which will remove some Registry keys recursively using API **RegDeleteKey** or **RegDeleteKeyEx**. What is bothering me is that **RegDeleteKeyEx** is not defined for less than **XP x64 Professional**, so now this limitation is limiting my app. Is there any way in which I can use both APIs with compatibility from XP x86 to Win7 x64 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for your app to run in old systems where `RegDeleteKeyEx` does not exist, you need to avoid static linking to this API. That is, you don't use this function directly, adn instead you obtain its pointer on runtime via `GetProcAddress`. If it succeeds, then the API is available and you can use it (alternatively you can check OS version).

Have a look here: [How can I use RegDeleteKeyEx](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/43cc1a76-4295-49bf-b2f9-da90dcefd82b):

```
   hAdvAPI32 = LoadLibrary(_T("AdvAPI32.dll"));
   ASSERT(hAdvAPI32 != NULL);
   _RegDeleteKeyEx = (PFN_RegDeleteKeyEx)GetProcAddress(hAdvAPI32 , "RegDeleteKeyEx");
   ASSERT(_RegDeleteKeyEx != NULL);
```

`RegDeleteKey` can be used directly since it exists in all target platforms.

Comment: Thanks mate, you saved me a lot of trouble :-)

Comment: @RomanR: "alternatively you can check OS version" - that only works if you delay-load the function at compile-time (which uses dynamic-loading at runime).

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: One might want to check version before going into LoadModule/GetProcAddress. This makes sense if one needs to locate several functions at once, or when function exists but does not do whta it is expected to do (stub only). What you say also works of course (delay load DLL and version check to not call the actually missing function).