# How to delete registry key on XP while having control over platform-specific view of the registry

Tags: c++, winapi, registry, windows-xp, wow64

This is a followup question of: [RegDeleteKey and RegDeleteKeyEx](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12797905/1798187)

#### Background

So, I have a C++ windows application that uses [RegDeleteKey function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/he-il/library/windows/desktop/ms724845(v=vs.85).aspx).
However, I need to control the *platform-specific view of the registry*.

So, based on this:

> 64-bit Windows:  On WOW64, 32-bit applications view a registry tree
> that is separate from the registry tree that 64-bit applications view.
> To enable an application to delete an entry in the alternate registry
> view, use the RegDeleteKeyEx function

Using [RegDeleteKeyEx function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/he-il/library/windows/desktop/ms724847(v=vs.85).aspx) is great when your app runs on Vista and above, but what about XP?

#### Question

How to delete registry key on XP while having control over *platform-specific view of the registry*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RegDeleteKeyEx` exists on every platform that has a 64 bit version with WOW64. You use it on those platforms. Otherwise you can use `RegDeleteKey`. And it doesn't matter that it isn't aware of registry views since you won't be calling it on a platform that has different registry views.

64 bit Windows was introduced after XP. There was a 64 bit version of XP and a corresponding 64 bit version of server 2003. These were the first versions that offered 64 bits with WOW64 and both support `RegDeleteKeyEx`.

Comment: Does `RegDeleteKeyEx()` exported from `advapi32.dll` in XP 64 bit?

Comment: Well yes. It is documented such in the documentation you link to in the question.

Comment: That's solve my problem but it raises another question: What if you want, on XP, to control other _Security and Access Rights_ using `samDesired` that are not related to registry view?

Comment: That's a different question. And I don't even understand it as stated here.

Comment: using `RegDeleteKeyEx()` give you the ability to control _Security and Access Rights_. You said that "_you can use `RegDeleteKey` And it doesn't matter that it isn't aware of registry views since you won't be calling it on a platform that has different registry views_". I agree. However what if the access right I want to use in function `RegDeleteKeyEx()` is **not** related to the registry views. Then it **would matter** switching from `RegDeleteKeyEx()` to `RegDeleteKey()`

Comment: When deleting a key the registry view is the only information that can be passed in samDesired